# OpenCV polyLines() throws error: (-215:Assertion failed) p.checkVector(2, CV_32S) >= 0 in function 'polylines'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, yolov8

I am trying to draw a segmentation mask from a YOLO segmentation mask dataset. The annotation line I am reading looks like this:

`36 0.6158357764423077 0.814453125 0.6158357764423077 0.8095703125 0.6070381225961539 0.8095703125 0.6041055721153846 0.8115234375 0.5894428149038462 0.8154296875 0.5747800576923077 0.8125 0.5513196490384615 0.8134765625 0.5483870961538462 0.81640625 0.5923753653846154 0.818359375 0.6158357764423077 0.814453125`

I am using cv2.polylines to draw the shape but am getting an error:

```
image_height, image_width, c = img.shape
isClosed = True
color = (255, 0, 0)
thickness = 2

with open(annotation_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        split_line = line.split()
        class_id = split_line[0]
        mask_shape = [float(numeric_string) for numeric_string in split_line[1:len(split_line)]]
        mask_points = []
        for i in range(0,len(mask_shape),2):
            x,y = mask_shape[i:i+2]
            mask_points.append((x * image_width, y * image_height))
        points = np.array([mask_points])
        image = cv2.polylines(img, points,
                              isClosed, color, thickness)
        break
```

Error:

`OpenCV(4.7.0) /Users/xperience/GHA-OCV-Python/_work/opencv-python/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp:2434: error: (-215:Assertion failed) p.checkVector(2, CV_32S) >= 0 in function 'polylines'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue of the `.dtype`. `points.dtype` must be `np.int32`. `polyLines` wants integers, not floats.

The values you insert into your list are all floats. The array would have had `float64` dtype.

Just call this:

```py
# points array for one polyline
points = np.array(mask_points, dtype=np.int32)

# polyLines takes a list of polylines
# you have one polyline, so it'll be a list of one element
image = cv2.polylines(
    img,
    [points], # one polyline
    isClosed, color, thickness)
```

Putting the outer dimension into the numpy array itself (you did that with `[mask_points]`), instead of using an outer list, is only acceptable if ALL your polylines have the same number of points.